# Convert form design from C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, converters, designer

By accident I unknowingly started a new C# project instead of VB and proceeded to build a rather complex form in the designer. It wasn't until I wanted to start coding that I realized I selected the wrong language by mistake.

I was wondering if it was possible to convert my C# form design, or import it so it can be used (and written) in a VB.Net solution.

All my searches have come up with topics centered and focused around the main program code, which is not necessary for me because I haven't written anything yet.

I have tried to take the designer code and convert it with an online tool followed by starting a VB project and replacing the fresh form's designer code but that just ended up breaking it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should just start over.

Comment: That's plan B. I was designing it for a couple hours and hoping there might be a 3 click solution built into Visual Studio

Comment: Or switch to WPF :) XAML is portable

Comment: You can select all the controls, copy them to the clipboard and paste into the VB form.  event code wont go with it though.  NET controls are NET controls, it wont care where they were created

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: One more solution, upload all code in **Form.Designer.cs** on some [website](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) just for this purpose, and convert to vb.net, then paste into your newly created **Form.Designer.vb**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Plutonix's comment, the solution was found in copying the control objects in the form designer and pasting them in the new project. It was not a perfect representation, but the flaws were so minor it was easily made right.

So simple!

Comment: You should clarify "designer" - copying designer code wont work...never mind - did it for youi